# How to perform aggregatin on NorthWind SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am trying to aggregate NorthWind tables `Products` and `Categories` such that I can get a list of product category names with counts of product in each category

Code tried so far:

```
SELECT 
    Categories.CategoryName, Categories.CategoryID
FROM 
    Categories 
LEFT JOIN 
    Products ON Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID;
```

Above code shows the categories. However, when I perform Group by on Category ID it shows an error saying

> Column 'Categories.CategoryName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

I am not sure what is wrong.

Note: I am new to SQL Server

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `COUNT()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. I tried GROUP BY (Categories.CategoryID).count(Categories.CategoryName) and it throws an error saying "Cannot call methods on int"

Comment: Hint, move the count into the Select clause @Biggboss2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for the `GROUP BY` is:

```
SELECT c.CategoryName, c.CategoryID, COUNT(p.CategoryID)
FROM Categories c LEFT JOIN
     Products p
    ON p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
GROUP BY c.CategoryName, c.CategoryID;
```

Note that this introduces table aliases, which make the query easier to write and to read.

All the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` are in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add a GROUP BY, you can no longer reference any element from the original set except for the expressions that appear in the GROUP BY clause, or an aggregate function on any other.
The reason is that after the GROUP BY, the set will consist of a single row per group, and the only value that is guaranteed to be the same is the GROUP BY Expression. For all other columns, you must guarantee a single value, and the only way to do that is by using an aggregate function - by definition it takes a set of values, and returns a single one.
That's why if you GROUP BY category id, you can't reference category name.
since I guess in your case they are functionally dependent, you can either add both to the GROUP BY clause, or add a dummy aggregate to category name.

```
SELECT Categories.CategoryName, Categories.CategoryID, COUNT(*) AS CountProducts
FROM   Categories 
       LEFT JOIN 
       Products 
       ON Products.CategoryID=Categories.CategoryID
GROUP BY Categories.CategoryName, Categories.CategoryID

OR

SELECT MAX(Categories.CategoryName) AS CategoryName, Categories.CategoryID, COUNT(*) AS CountProducts
FROM   Categories 
       LEFT JOIN 
       Products 
       ON Products.CategoryID=Categories.CategoryID
GROUP BY Categories.CategoryID
```

Comment: Thank you explaining Aggregation and Group By!